# How can I stack up a series of numpy arrays faster?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-xarray

I have an `xarray` `DataArray` with the following dimensions:

```
 vals.shape
(210, 587, 1, 1)
```

it contains a single value for 210 different species over 587 different dates. I would like to form an array that is species x species for each day where on a given day every row of that matrix contains the same normalized (sum to one) values of the species for that day (i.e. where index `(i,j)` of the matrix on a given date contains the the value for species `j` on that day). I also need the end array to have an extra dimension `I` and be ordered `Species x Dates x I x Species`

I can currently achieve this by doing the following:

```
#form a list of species x species matrices:
daily_arrays = [np.array([vals[:, i, 0, 0] for n in range(210)]) for i in 587]

#normalize rows to sum to 1 on each day
daily_arrays = [x / x.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] for x in daily_arrays]

#stack them up and throw on the `I` dimension
desired_array = np.stack([np.stack(daily_arrays, axis=1)], axis=2)
```

Unfortunately this is currently taking over 3 hours (the bottleneck is building the `daily_arrays` list). How can I express this more efficiently?

Comment: I'm not familiar with xarray, you absolutely must do this with NumPy?

Comment: @AMC, I don't have to do it with numpy, i could always convert in the end to whatever is needed so could use whatever for the construction steps.

Comment: _i could always convert in the end to whatever is needed_ What is needed, then?

Comment: in the end i convert to an internal data structure which currently uses an `xarray` implementation and just write it out to disk.There's no need for me to even use `numpy` if I could do the above quickly with native `xarray` types

Comment: _There's no need for me to even use numpy if I could do the above quickly with native xarray types_ There probably is, eh.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be dipping back down into python loops to rearrange your numpy array. This will be slow on big datasets, as you have found. To rearrange columns, use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

You can go from your (210, 587, 1, 1) array to a (587, 210, 1, 1) very quickly with:

```
daily_arrays = np.transpose(vals, (1, 0, 2, 3))
```

This will give you a row for each day and a column for each species.

With that you can normalize in numpy as well without the python loop using:

```
daily_arrays/daily_arrays(axis = 1, keepdims=1)
```

I'm not really sure why your data is 4-dimensional (why not just use a 210 x 587 matrix) — but I'll assume you have a reason for the extra single-value dimensions.

Comment: Thanks let me play around with this and see if i can build the same desired array without loops. Yes my desired array is 3 dimensional (practically) but I need to shove a dummy fourth dimension for compatibility with another API. Same goes for the seemingly redundant row copies in each dates matrix - it's the structure expected by a 3rd party application consuming this array off disk later.

Answer (score 1):

Per Mark's suggestion to avoid python loops for the rearrangement and more time spent on `xarray` documentation and an interpreter the following solves the problem in about 1 second without leaving `xarray`:

```
vals = vals / vals.sum(dim="species")

desired_array = xarray.concat([vals[:, :, :, :] for n in range(210)], "items")
desired_array = desired_array.transpose("items", "dates", "I", "species")
```

I don't need to shove a dimension in because I preserve it from the original `210 x 587 x 1 x 1` array I started with.